# Is it possible to solve this system of equation, if not why not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Is it possible to solve this system of equation, if not why not?

$$\left[\begin{matrix}-\alpha_1&0\\0&-\alpha_2\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}1&{-\beta}_1\\{-\beta}_2&1\\\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}=\left[\begin{matrix}0.25&0\\0.25&0.25\\\end{matrix}\right]$$

To give some context, I am trying to simulate a system of equations based on a specified error term structure and this is a problem that I have come across.

What I have tried:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}-\alpha_1&0\\0&-\alpha_2\\\end{matrix}\right]\frac{1}{1+(\beta_1\beta_2)}\left[\begin{matrix}1&\beta_1\\\beta_2&1\\\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}0.25&0\\0.25&0.25\\\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: Hi! I want to remind you that it is generally preferred you include context when asking a question here (which can include: where this problem came from, your own attempts, and a *specific* idea as to where you're stuck) - it also lets us help you better! As is, your question is little more than an isolated problem, and thus likely to get a lot of downvotes and closed. Feel free to [edit] the context into your post though! Here's a useful link: [asking a good question](https://goo.gl/11Cojp).

Comment: Please inform me of the downvote

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps you can try evaluating the left-hand side.

Comment: Hi @MattiP. this is what I have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $\left[\begin{matrix}-\alpha_1&0\\0&-\alpha_2\\\end{matrix}\right]\frac{1}{1+(\beta_1\beta_2)}\left[\begin{matrix}1&\beta_1\\\beta_2&1\\\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}0.25&0\\0.25&0.25\\\end{matrix}\right]$

We get

$\frac{1}{1+\beta_1\beta_2}\left[\begin{matrix}-\alpha_1&- \alpha_1 \beta_1\\\alpha_2 \beta_2&-\alpha_2\\\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}0.25&0\\0.25&0.25\\\end{matrix}\right]$.

Since $ \alpha_1 \ne 0$, we derive  from $\alpha_1 \beta_1=0$, that $ \beta_1=0.$

Hence we have

$\left[\begin{matrix}-\alpha_1&0\\\alpha_2 \beta_2&-\alpha_2\\\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}0.25&0\\0.25&0.25\\\end{matrix}\right]$.

This yields $\alpha_1= \alpha_2 =-0.25$ and $ \beta_2=-1.$

Comment: Thanks Fred!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

**A Hint, not a complete solution**

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}-\alpha_1&0\\0&-\alpha_1\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}1&\beta_1\\\beta_1&1\\\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}=\left[\begin{matrix}0.25&0\\0.25&0.25\\\end{matrix}\right]
$$
can be rewritten as 
$$
4\left[\begin{matrix}-\alpha_1&0\\0&-\alpha_1\\\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\1&1\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}1&\beta_1\\\beta_1&1\\\end{matrix}\right]
$$
(with the condition that $1 - \beta_1^2 \ne 0$, so that the rightmost matrix is invertible).

Evaluating the upper left hand corner of each side we get
$$
-4 \alpha_1 = 1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot \beta_1 = 1.
$$
So if there's a solution, then
$$
\alpha_1 = -\frac{1}{4}.
$$
I suspect you can look at the other four equations similarly, and rapidly discover whether there's a solution or not.

Comment: In the updated problem, is there no way of a solution

Comment: @user30609, You know, you are supposed to do something yourself, not just wait for other people. This is a wonderful hint which you should use

Comment: Do you know how to multiply two matrices?

Comment: @JohnHughes yes but Im not very confident

Comment: Then I'd say it's time to practice until you are; otherwise trying to work with things like this will be impossible for you.

Comment: Wait...you edited the problem after I'd already answered, replacing one of the $\alpha_1$s with an $\alpha_2$, and similarly for $\beta$? Jeez...now this makes my answer look stupid. Sigh.

Comment: @JohnHughes I did let you know, sorry about that, typo!